# C# Create user control without creating new project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do i create new user control with only create new files on current project (i mean we do not have to create new class library project)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the current project and select "Add->New Item". Select "Visual C# Items" and then "User Control".

Comment: Thanks you, how about component? i already created a component but how can i place it in to form?

Comment: Same thing, but use Add->Existing Item

Comment: I mean i have created a component in my project and how can use this component?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: If you think this post answers your question helpfully, you should mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: If you have created a component in your project, you should have it available at the top in the toolbox. Drag it from there.